# C# linq .FirstOrDefault() to get more elements from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Last time I ask about linq, how to get information about element  from my database if there is possibility that object exist or not. The answer was:

```
 var elements = XElement.Load("objects.xml");
    var query1 = from query in elements.Descendants("Lemma")
                let null_LemmaSign = query.Element("Lemma.LemmaSign")
                et null_TE = query.Descendants("TE.TE").FirstOrDefault()
                where wyszuk == query.Element("Lemma.LemmaSign").Value
                select new
                {
                  word = null_LemmaSign == null ? "none" : null_LemmaSign.Value,
                  te = null_TE == null ? "none" : null_TE.Value,
                };

    foreach (var e in query1)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(e.word.ToString() + " - " + e.te.ToString());
    }
```

Other possibility was

```
let null_TE = query.Element("Sense").Element("TE").Element("TE.TE")
```

But now I have situation that I have to get more than first element of `<TE>`.

Example from database (now I can pick only first item, cat, but I wish to collect them all)

```
<TE><TE.TE> cat</TE.TE></TE>,<TE><TE.TE> cat2</TE.TE></TE>,<TE><TE.TE> cat3</TE.TE></TE>
```

Comment: ... and the question is?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ToList()` instead of the `.FirstOrDefault()`. The second line in the `select` clause will have to change since you will be dealing with a list instead of a single element

Note that the list will never be null but it could contain 0 items.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use .Take() and use the number of elements you want

Also useful function is .Skip()

so it is easy to do something like paging for instance with a combination of them.